# VM with windows 10 on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: windows-10, 17.04

I have stopped using Windows completely and my machine is solely on Linux/ Ubuntu.I don't use VM at all.

I wonder if I can install a VM with Windows 10 on my Ubuntu? Do I need a full license copy of Windows 10 before I can run it in the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be explicitly clear,

- Yes, you can install Windows 10 in a VM with an Ubuntu host provided you have sufficient RAM, disk space, etc.
- Yes, you need a licensed copy of Windows 10. This means you're going to need a valid *retail* (not OEM) product key if you want to run it as a guest OS.
- If you have a retail copy of a different Windows version that is not being used, you might be able to install that first and then upgrade it (cheaper?), but I'm not sure what versions you can directly upgrade from.

Comment: i think i will forget about VM and Windows. As I just need to run  C# apps that are Microsoft bound. So  Visual Studio 2017 is needed. But it seems that I can use  MonoProject  instead https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1072008/Guide-for-building-Csharp-apps-on-Ubuntu-MonoProje

Answer (score 0):

You can install any kind or variety of Windows 10 you like in a virtual machine on Ubuntu. It will be subject to exactly the same restrictions and limitations due to versioning and licensing that it would if you installed it on a real PC.

Comment: i don't understand. so i need a Windows 10 licence?

Comment: If you need a license to install it for real, you need a license for the vm. If your question is about windows licensing, it is off topic here.